# Como trabalhar com MultipartFile no Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot

Ainda estou em processo de implementação de upload de imagens, veja o código abaixo;

```
@PostMapping
        public String upload(@RequestParam("files[]") MultipartFile[] files) {
        System.out.println("files >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> "  + files.length);
        return "ok";

    }
```

Estou usando o STS do Spring Boot, depois de selecionar a imagem usando o Postman o resultado foi **0** invés de ter retornando **1** como pode ver abaixo no console do STS;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para conseguir retorna 1 ?

Comment: Partindo do principio que o input seja "files", tente substituir o `@RequestParam("files[]")`  por `@RequestParam("files")`

Comment: infelizmente isso não funcionou.